# How to get an immediate callback when MediaPlayer couldn't play source and is retrying?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How do I get an immediate callback when MediaPlayer couldn't play the source (say invalid url) and is retrying? Right now, MediaPlayer.onError() only gets called after ALL 10 retries have failed and that takes way too long. Alternatively, i'd like to limit the number of retries.

This is what the logcat is like:

On a separate process:

```
E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 10 retries left
E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 9 retries left

...

E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 0 retries left
```

Finally on my app's process:

```
MediaPlayer.onError()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have no means to set retry time ,but you may use

```
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

that wouldn't block your ui thread.

if you really wan't to set retry time ,this answer may help.[third party framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43109373/5137081)