# Android Mediaplayer doesnt throw IO exception If file not available at the link

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am starting mediaplayer with a URL. The URL suppose to link to a video/Audio  . But i have deleted the video/audio file from the location, hence i would like to expect a IOException id there is nothing available at that link.

But i am not getting the IO exception. Instead mediaplayer itself try to go to the linkl 10 times and finally throw the error on onErrorListner. 
follwings are the logs printed while mediaPlayer is preparing.

**Note: - my url is not for local storaged file!! its for server side file.**

```
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 10 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 9 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 8 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 7 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 6 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 5 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 4 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 3 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 2 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 1 retries left
 E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 0 retries left
 E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
```

I do not want to wait so long that mediaplayer try to reconnect with the same URL 10 time. I want the IOException or error immediately on the very first time.

following is my code. Kindly help!!

```
  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(url));
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                    OnErrorReceive("Something is wrong with media player states");

                    return false;
                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    enter code here
               strong text     mMediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are playing with remote media resources, I'd recommend other mediaPlayer implementation like [google/ExoPlayer2](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

The retry count of Android default player is 10. There is no error handling on HTTP 404 response.

```
struct NuCachedSource2 : public DataSource {

...
enum {
    kMaxNumRetries = 10,
};
```

google/ExoPlayer2 has 2. But you can change if you want. [my commit in github](https://github.com/YouKim/ExoPlayer/commit/63748b64ce179e4f7081d1c0f718b251412d0fd4)

```
      if (retryAction == DONT_RETRY_FATAL) {
        fatalError = currentError;
      } else if (retryAction != DONT_RETRY) { // DONT_RETRY = 2
        errorCount = retryAction == RETRY_RESET_ERROR_COUNT ? 1 : errorCount + 1;
        start(getRetryDelayMillis());
      }
```

Comment: Hi we are not planning to use any third party library, Morever we are just making a basic audio/video player which is just a small part of a project. Hence i would like to seek the help from you!! I am just using Android Mediaplayer API. How can i change this kMaxNumRetries  from 10 to 1 or 2.  DO i have to use NDK?

Comment: If you access remote media resources using HTTP protocol, use simple HTTP client and check response code at the same time. I think It is very hard to change default retry count in Android media framework.

Answer (score 0):

Android Mediaplayer doesn't throw an exception if the link is wrong with prepareAsync(). 
For prepareAsync try to catch your errors using:

```
onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra);
```

using MediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener().

Instead use `mMediaPlayer.prepare();`

Another alternative is to use

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

to check right away if your link exists!

Comment: I am listening with onError but the problem is that it takes too long at least 30 seconds to respond. when i saw the logs i found out the mediaplayer internally receive 404 error but tries 10 times to reconnect and finally throws the error. trying 10 time to reconnect takes more than 30 secnds.  have a look above at my question . i hvae written the logs where u can see mediaplayer tries 10 times and the report the error

Comment: mMediaPlayer.prepare() doesn't solves the purpose at all.  URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)  is just to see whether url is valis or not. here my concern is that URL is valid. but we have removed the content from the server corresponding to this url. Now i want the IOException as soon as possible. by default it takes around 30-40 seconds after checking 10 times like i have mentioned in the question

Comment: @user2228673 if you don't want to wait, URLUtil.isValidUrl(url) is your best bet. There are lots of limitations in MediaPlayer API. You could try building your own player using NDK. But it would require time and lots of works.

Comment: I couldn't understand how URLUtil.isValidUrl(url) can solve my problem. If you look at the isValidUrl. it just check whether it is http or ot, file orl or not etc etc. It doesn't go to server and check whether contents available at that url or not. In my case url is valid url, only problem is there is no content available at server at this URL. In my application i have to handle this case , hence delibrated i have deleted content from this url so that i can catch IOException at mediaplayer if content is not available at the server.

Answer (score 0):

IOException is thrown when setDataSource(String path) is called and file does not exist.

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url)
        final String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        if ("file".equals(scheme)) {
            path = uri.getPath();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path); // IOException
        } else {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), uri);
        }
```

Comment: my url is not for local file. i have the files at my server, hence i am using mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), uri);  as you can see form my code as well and i am not getting IOException. instead whatever logs i get , i have pasted already. it checks 10 time and than return error on onErrorListner